# Find the average of fields in the columns

Tags: linux, sed, awk

I have a record like this

```
1  11  11  T  A  0  0  A=1;B=2,C=3;D=4;
```

there are 8 columns and each columns is separated by tab space

and I need the output is like this

```
1  11  11  T  A  0  0  A=1;B=2,C=3;D=4;AF=2.5;
```

Where `AF` is the average of all fields in the 8th column.

```
AF=(1+2+3+4)/4=2.5
```

Comment: What did you try? What is the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you intput data is really nice: space, comma, semicolon... try this:

```
awk -F'[;, ]' '{n=0;s=0;for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)
if($i~/=[0-9]+/){split($i,t,"=");n++;s+=t[2]; } 
print $0"AF="s/n";"
}' file
```

with your data:

```
kent$  echo "1 11 11 T A 0 0 A=1;B=2,C=3;D=4;"|awk -F'[;, ]' '{n=0;s=0;for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) 
if($i~/=[0-9]+/){split($i,t,"=");n++;s+=t[2]; }
print $0"AF="s/n";"
}' 
1 11 11 T A 0 0 A=1;B=2,C=3;D=4;AF=2.5;
```

Comment: Actually in original file 8th column contains 7 fields each fields are separated by semi columns.While I am running the command the AF is coming on the next line.kindly help us to include the AF field on the same line.

Comment: it is in same line here. and should be in same line there too. did you copy the command? also paste one line of your real data.

Comment: My input files contains more than one records

Comment: @AbhinRaj that is not a problem! you have 100 lines, my command outputs 100 lines, with avg at the end of each line with `AF=(value);` as you wished. btw, don't post same question multi-times